# Getting SqlCommand with EF

Tags: entity-framework, sqldependency

I made a SqlDependency service in my application. It works perfectly when I type the queries by hand but I cannot include wildcards (I don't really know why).

For example:

```
//Using this SqlCommand will work
new SqlCommand("SELECT [employees].[name] FROM [dbo].[employees]", sqlNotificationConn)

//But this one won't
new SqlCommand("SELECT [employees].* FROM [dbo].[employees]", sqlNotificationConn)

//And this one won't either
new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[employees]", sqlNotificationConn)
```

So basically, I want to get my DbContext to generate a full SELECT command with every fields it deals with.

In Linq 2 SQL, I used this service using `dbContext.GetCommand(.....);`

In EF 4.0 (or was it 4.1?), I used `dbContext.employee.ToTraceString();`

But in EF 4.4, I can't find anything to generate that SELECT query string....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `DbContext` (`DbQuery`) it is as simple as:

```
query.ToString()
```

With `ObjectContext` (`ObjectQuery`):

```
((ObjectQuery)query).ToTraceString()
```

By the way, `query` can be any expression based on a `DbSet` (or `ObjectSet`, respectively). So something like `dbContext.employee.Where(e => e.Name == "Gates").ToString()` will also show the generated SQL query.

A LINQ statement that forces execution, like `ToList()`, `Single()`, `FirstOrDefault()`, etc, creates a new object and `ToString()` will return the object's type name.

Comment: So simple... Thanks! (Ps. It's not only for Code-First. I'm using Database-First and it works)

Comment: So if i have: _dbContext.Stuffs.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Key == "MyKey"); how do i get the query for that?

Comment: @GertArnold, I must be doing something wrong completely. For me the `ToString()` returns the type name if the query was successful, or throws a `System.NullReferenceException`. here's the listing: `_dbContext = new SettingsConnection();

            Debug.WriteLine(_dbContext.Stuffs.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Key == "MyKey").ToString());`

Comment: @zaitsman No, I was wrong, sorry. Just a bit too hasty. See my addition.

Answer (score 0):

`ToTraceString()` is still in EF, same place it always was. However, it's on `ObjectQuery`, not `DbQuery`. Having said that, I've never seen the SQL Server provider for EF use `*`; it always uses discrete fields in SQL.

Comment: Then how can I use it on EF4.4 context?